# Retain property structure with recursive property iteration

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, properties

The problem I'm facing with this code is that it doesn't use the same structure to declare the properties in the callback.

For instance, if the function ends up with a property `options.foo.bar`, in the callback it would declare `self.bar`, but I want it to retain the same structure so it should be `self.foo.bar`.

How can I achieve that?

```
function forEachProperty(object, callback) {
    for (var property in object) {
        if (!object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (object[property].constructor === Object) {
            this.forEachProperty(object[property], callback);
        } else {
            callback(object, property);
        }
    }
}

// Usage
forEachProperty(options, function (object, property) {
    if (property !== 'timeUrl' && property !== 'element') {
        self[property] = object[property];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function forEachProperty(loc,object, callback) {
    for (var property in object) {
        if (!object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (object[property].constructor === Object) {
            if(loc[property]===undefined)loc[property]={};
            this.forEachProperty(loc[property],object[property], callback);
        } else {
            callback(loc,object, property);
        }
    }
}

var self={bar:{baz:999}};
var options={test:'hello world',bar:{foo:8}}

// Usage
forEachProperty(self,options, function (loc,object, property) {
    if (property !== 'timeUrl' && property !== 'element') {
        loc[property] = object[property];
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that when I have an object `var self = { bar: 'test', baz: 'test' }`, and the options object has only `bar` property, it only sets the `bar` property to self, it should also retain the `baz` property. In your case the `baz` property is removed and only the `bar` property is set.

Comment: how can you retain `baz` preperty from `options` while it doesn't have it

Comment: The declaration `loc[property] = object[property];` should only *override* properties from `loc`. So if `self` has `{ bar: 1, baz: 2 }`, and the `options` object passed to the function has `{ bar: 999 }`, `self` should now be `{ bar: 999, baz: 2 }` and not `{ bar: 999 }`. Kind of like merging them together.

Comment: make sure you are retrieving self and not options. because I tried it and I get `options = { bar: 999 }` and `self = { bar: 999, baz: 2 }`

Comment: I think the problem only occurs when the object is 2+ levels deep. If options is `{ bar: { foo: 1; bar: 2 }, baz: 3} }`, `bar.bar` will be gone.

Comment: I think we you misunderstand the function.

its Usage is:

`var self =  { bar: 999, baz: 2 };`
`var options = { bar: { foo: 1, bar: 2 }, baz: 3};`

`forEachProperty(self,options, function (loc,object, property) {
    if (property !== 'timeUrl' && property !== 'element') {
        loc[property] = object[property];
    }
});`

`console.log(self); // Object { bar: Object, baz: 3 }`
`console.log(self.bar); // Object { foo: 1, bar: 2 }`

so it's overriding `self.bar` by the value of options exactly as you want. if it's not tell me what.

Comment: It's the other way around. If `self = { foo: { bar: 1, baz: 2 } }` and you try to override it with `options = { foo: { bar: 3 } }`, `self` will now be `{ foo: { bar: 3 } } // baz is gone`,  because when it matches `bar`, you set `loc[property] = {}` which mean *all* of the *other* properties it still has to loop over are **lost** because you set the property to a plain object. It should be `{ foo: { bar: 3, baz: 2 } } //bazz is still there`.

Comment: finallly I undersand you, answer edited to check for existance of `loc[property]` before assignment